# Why does for loop brake earlier than it should?

Tags: java, for-loop, anagram

So I have a `for` loop that looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < al.size(); j++) {
        if (isAnagram(al.get(i), al.get(j))) {
            al.set(i, al.get(i) + " " + al.get(j));
            al.remove(j);
        }
    }
}
```

`al` is ArrayList with words (strings) in it, let's say it looks like this:

```
[aabb, aabc, abab, abba, abcd, bbaa, cbad]
```

and `isAnagram` returns `true` or `false` if two given strings are anagrams or not.
I'm trying to make it add all anagrams for each word to to one string so it would look like that:

```
[aabb abab abba bbaa, aabc, abcd cbad]
```

and right now I'm getting:

```
[aabb abab, aabc, abba bbaa, abcd cbad]
```

So what i think is happening - the second `for` ends whenever it finds first anagram for `al.get(i)` and than it breaks and goes for next `i`. Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: You cannot remove item like this in an array list   `al.remove(j);` you should use Iterator

Comment: Removing `ul.remove(j);` doesn't help after removing it I get:
`[aabb abab, aabc, abab abba, abba bbaa, abcd cbad, bbaa, cbad]` - it still cant go further than one anagram for one string

Comment: One solution is Insert `j--;` inside if condition after removing ` al.remove(j);`

Comment: Adding `j--;` also doesn't help. Output is still: `[aabb abab, aabc, abba bbaa, abcd cbad]`

Comment: Put `i--;` insted of `j--;`

Comment: @Uit14bs No.  `j--;` is correct but there's another problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list:

```
[aabb, aabc, abab, abba, abcd, bbaa, cbad]
```

When `j=2`, you will be looking at `abab`.  You find that it's an anagram, so you modify the earlier element and remove `abab`.  Here's what your list now looks like:

```
[aabb abab, aabc, abba, abcd, bbaa, cbad]
```

There are now 2 problems.  First, `"abba"` used to be `al.get(3)`, but now it's `al.get(2)`.  But when you loop back, you increment `j`, so `j` is now 3.  The result is that your code never looks at `"abba"`.

The other problem is that even if your code did look at `"abba"`, it would not find that it's an anagram.  This is because you've destroyed the string you were comparing it to, i.e. `al.get(i)` where `i==0`.  This string was `"aabb"`, but now it's `"aabb abab"`.  So your logic will no longer work.

There are two things you'll need to do:

(1) Rearrange your loop so that you do not increment `j` when you remove an element; you increment `j` only when you don't remove it.  Personally, I'd use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop to accomplish this.  [For what it's worth, I don't like the practice of modifying the index variable that you're using in a `for` loop; I think makes code less readable, because to me the usual `for` loop with `j++` as the third part looks like you're going to execute the body for every integer in a sequence, and modifying `j` in the middle of the loop contradicts that appearance.  Others think it's OK, though.]

(2) Don't modify `al.get(i)` (that is, don't call `al.set(i,new value)`) until you no longer need it in your anagram checks, i.e. when the inner loop is completed.  You'll have to declare a variable to hold the new string, and then call `al.set` later.